# Why Axios' onUploadProgress never triggers when callin third party API in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, azure, axios, backend

the axios.post sends a file to an Azure hosted backend API. It is in Typescript

```
const headers:AxiosRequestHeaders = { "Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*", "Content-Type": file[0].type};

axios.post("https://xxxxxxx.azurewebsites.net/api/SpeechToText", formdata, {headers,onUploadProgress :(progressEvent) => {
      const progress = (progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total) * 90;
      console.log(progressEvent)
      setSingleProgress(progress)
      
    }})
```

basically even console.log is not showing anything so I assume the whole function was never triggered. I don't find any problem on the code itself, but please ask if more information needed from me.

Answer (score 0):

- I think this is auth issue you don't have auth token added in the header that might be why you are not being able to trigger the function
- you can get the function URL along with auth tokens attached to it, in the portal which then you can use in the axios.

under `function` tag select the desired function

[image]

Then click on the `Get Function Url`  and copy the URL and use that in axios.

[image]

[image]